# What does Time Machine "server data" mean?

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server, osx-leopard, time-machine

I see in an Apple [manual](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Getting_Started_v10.5.pdf) that

> "Time Machine backup of server data
>   isn’t supported for an advanced
>   server"

but I'm not clear on how to interpret "***server data***." Does it refer to the entire boot volume for the server... or certain folders... all volumes connected?

While only Apple knows exactly how to interpret the phrase, I'm hoping someone here may have figured out by trial and error.

Any useful information is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Probably databases. Databases carry an ACID guarantee that you want, but those guarantees are only available from the running database program. The database files aren't usually enough to guarantee a consistent database state.

Traditionally, you skip files known to be databases and run database dumps instead.